# Blackduck reports are empty and console logs pip inspect errors

Tags: python, blackduck, synopsis-detect

Below are the blackduck scan step.I am running a pipeline that has blackduck stage :

> - ./detect.sh --blackduck.url=https://blackduck.project-tools.com --blackduck.api.token=**** --detect.parent.project.name=cicd_tma-ggg-Mtr --detect.parent.project.version.name=1.0.0 --detect.project.tier=2 --blackduck.trust.cert=true --detect.blackduck.signature.scanner.paths=dd_emr_common --detect.excluded.detector.types=MAVEN --detect.tools.excluded=SIGNATURE_SCAN --logging.level.com.synopsys.integration=DEBUG --detect.project.version.name=0.0.1 --detect.python.python3=true --detect.detector.search.continue=true --detect.cleanup=false --detect.report.timeout=1500 --blackduck.timeout=3000 --detect.project.codelocation.unmap=true --detect.pip.requirements.path=requirements.txt --detect.tool=ALL

Jenkins console logs:

```
  https: //pastebin.com/3qAnhQ1R
```

My worry is that I am getting pip inspector errors as notified in the logs. Also, I dont find anything in the report though I have never used blackduck ever, i ma still looking to browse its documents.Could someone provide basic pointers as to where should I begin to investigate.

Blackduck report:

[image: Blackduck report]